# Spring webflow - access to session

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am trying to get the session attribute in spring webflow, but it doesn't work.  In some controllers I have:

```
User u = userDao.getUser(userName);
session.setAttribute("sessionUser", u);
```

In JSP, I can get it, and it works fine:

```
${sessionScope.sessionUser.getLogin()}
```

I tried something like this:

```
<decision-state id="isUserLogged">
    <if test="sessionUser.getLogin() != null" then="startView" else="start" />
</decision-state>
```

but I get the error:

```
EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'sessionUser' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl'
```

or

```
<decision-state id="isUserLogged">
        <if test="${sessionScope.sessionUser.getLogin()}" then="startView" else="start" />
    </decision-state>
```

error:

```
 EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

My first question is, how can I get `sessionUser` in webflow?

I also tried calling the controller method, because in controller method I can get `sessionUser`, but it doesn't work.

My second question is, how can I call controller method in webflow?

Answer (score 3):

There is no sessionScope in Spring Web Flow. To access an object on the Session, instead you'll need to use the externalContext implicit el-variable something like this:

```
<if test="externalContext.sessionMap.sessionUser.getLogin() != null" then="startView" else="start" />
```